# Getting user input as the program loop still runs

Tags: perl

I have a script that goes basically like this:

```
sub mainLoop {
    while (1) {
        # Do its thing
    }
}
```

I don't think the logic is important at all, it's basically constantly checking a server and doing some actions when necessary. But I want to make sure the user can input some commands as the program is running, like a `show status` or `show foo`. And print something, like the number of times it had to take action, etc. To sum it up, it needs to read from the STDIN without pausing the loop.

I read the source code of another Perl program that does this. But I'm not sure if I get it:

```
sub mainLoop {
    while (1) {
        # This is just for the sake of of this example
        my $bits = '';
        my $line = undef;

        vec($bits, fileno(STDIN), 1) = 1;

        if (select($bits, undef, undef, 0) > 0) {
            $line = <STDIN>;
            $line =~ s/\n//g;
        }

        if ($line) {
            # I can work with $line value and call a sub based on its value 
        }
        # Keep on doing its thing
    }
}
```

I don't get the `select()`. How does it change to a value greater than 0? Because as far as I can tell the value of `$bits` is the same whether the `select()` have a value equal to 0 or bigger than 0. So why does the value returned by select changes to a 1 whenever I hit the ENTER key?

Comment: I suggest you use the [IO::Select](http://metacpan.org/module/IO::Select) module instead, which wraps the `select` call in a much tidier API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` returns the highest file descriptor+1 in case some of the file descriptor was notified. Therefore it will be `0` if there is nothing on `STDIN` and 1 in case there is some bytes waiting to be read (note `STDIN` is fd `0` so `0+1` is 1 - the return value).